# Google search keep keywords in order in search results

Tags: search

I wanna search "nice beautiful" in a query at google ,how to **keep query terms in order in search results' texts** and the query isnt a phrase.
eg. each search result must like this pattern:  "...... nice .... beautiful ....."
BTW: *is there a way in which I can detect whether two words are adjacent adjectives*

Comment: that's not a programming question.

Comment: yes, it's about how to search the type

Comment: then it does not fit in Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
"nice * beautiful"
```

With the quotes. 
Use multiple stars or asterisks for a set of results where there are a little more words in between. 
Links: [nice * beautiful](https://www.google.com/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=6&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=nice%20%2a%20beautiful) and [nice ******** beautiful](https://www.google.com/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=6&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=nice%20%2a%2a%2a%20beautiful#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=nice%20%2a%2a%2a%2a%2a%2a%2a%2a%20beautiful&oq=nice%20%2a%2a%2a%2a%2a%2a%2a%2a%20beautiful&gs_l=serp.3..0i7i10i30j0i7i30l2j0i7i10i30.10608.11088.0.11420.5.5.0.0.0.3.131.607.0j5.5.0.les;..0.0...1c.1.3nUP6Mq6TGI&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=4d0493350179db3e&biw=1317&bih=656).

More information on wildcard characters in google search [here](http://www.googleguide.com/wildcard_operator.html).

Comment: is there a way in which I can detect whether two words are adjacent adjectives